# Comparison of symbolic calcualtion

Tags: matlab, calculation

I am trying to make the calculation of a Jacobian matrix on matlab. I calculate the matrix in two ways:

1- Manually calculating the derivatives of the function and then implementing it;
 2- I used symbols to write the function in Matlab, I used an embedded function to calculate derivatives and then evaluated the result.

The following is the results of an element of the matrix using the two methods:

0.812800813334022

0.812779921070141 (symbolic calculation)

I see that the two numbers agrees to the third figure only. My question is:

Which results should I trust?. (It may be evident that it is the one using symbolic calculation, If it is the case why?)

If the first methods is not accurate, how can I correct it (to avoid cancellation...)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The symbolic calculation should deliver the more precise result (typically). One reason for the loss of precision in numeric computation is that the derivative `df` of function `f(x)` is basically calculated by using finite differences:

```
df = (f(x+dx)-f(x))/dx
```

by decreasing `dx` you get closer to the true value but you increase the influence of rounding errors and limited precision of floating point calculations.

Comment: Thank you @Georg for your answer. In fact, when I said analytically, this means that using derivation rules for example (derivation of log(x) is 1/x etc.)...